# Numeric for loop in Dart Polymer templates

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

How do I write a numeric **for** loop in a polymer custom element template? I mean something like

```html
<template repeat="{{for i = 1 to 10}}">
<div>item</td>
</template>
```

Is it possible in the current version of Dart 1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently no, this is not possible in Polymer.dart (or Polymer.js to my knowledge). The repeat binding requires an iterable (See Repeating Templates section of the [Polymer_expressions](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions) library). Unfortunately due to [Issue 12669](http://dartbug.com/12669) it is also not possible to use a list literal to accomplish this either.

Using a filter we can accomplish this:

```html
<!-- myelement.html -->

<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <div>
      <template repeat="{{ 5 | myFilter }}">
        <p>Write me {{ }}</p>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="myelement.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
// myelement.dart

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:polymer_expressions/filter.dart';

@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  final Transformer myFilter = new GenerateIterable();

  MyElement.created() : super.created();

}

class GenerateIterable extends Transformer<Iterable, int> {
  int reverse(Iterable i) => i.length;
  Iterable forward(int i) => new Iterable.generate(i, (j) => j + 1);
}
```

Creating a page which imports myelement.html and using `<my-element></my-element>` will output:

```html
<div>
  <p>Write me 1</p>
  <p>Write me 2</p>
  <p>Write me 3</p>
  <p>Write me 4</p>
  <p>Write me 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope this will be possible in a next version of Dart.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how a simple filter can be created to accomplish the same

Comment: This solution doesn't work with nested templates like:

<tr template repeat="{{5 | filter}}"><td template repeat="{{6 | filter}}">1</td></tr>

Comment: While I can't be sure, I believe this may be related to: http://dartbug.com/12742 (basically that variables in the global template of the first aren't showing in the secondary template.